# ui:repeat with a list sending right object to a p:dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, commandlink

I currently have a giant ui:repeat. Within this ui:repeat, some of the repeated objects have a url to a popup image associated with them. When someone clicks display under that particular object, I need the url to popup in a p:dialog.

```
<ui:repeat var="thing" value="#{bean.thingList}">
    <p:commandLink value="details" onclick="miniImage.show();" 
    update=":#{p:component('chart')}"
    action="#{bean.setCurrentImg(thing.imageUrl)}" 
    rendered="#{thing.includeImage}">
</p:commandLink>
</ui:repeat>
```

and at the bottom of the page:

```
<p:dialog id="chart" widgetVar="miniImage" >
    <h:graphicImage value="#{bean.currentImg}"/>
</p:dialog>
```

And in the backing bean I tried using a simple setter and getter for currentImg.

I am a bit confused on this now and would like to accomplish this without having to submit the entire form as well. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using [PrimeFaces 3.3 or newer](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1842), you could just add [`partialSubmit="true"`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/partialSubmit.jsf) to the command component. You can then control the to-be-processed components in `process` attribute. In this particular case, just the current component (the command component itself) is sufficient, thus so `process="@this"`:

```
<p:commandLink ... process="@this" partialSubmit="true" />
```

This way only the request parameters which are really necessary for the process will be sent.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I suggest to use `oncomplete` instead of `onclick` to open the dialog. Otherwise the dialog is opened before `update` takes place and may cause poor user experience as the enduser would see the image instantly changing.